# Linux - How to get system DNS server IP on a system with systemd-resolved

Tags: c++, linux

Generally, on Linux, one would use the [res_init/res_ninit](https://linux.die.net/man/3/resolver) functions to get the system nameserver. I have tried this, but the resulting data gives me a DNS server ip of 127.0.0.53, which is the loopback IP of the systemd-resolved stub resolver. Needless to say, this is not the IP I'm looking for.

More specifically, I tried the following code:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/nameser.h>
#include <resolv.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct __res_state dns;
    res_ninit(&dns);

    uint32_t dnsSrv = dns.nsaddr_list[0].sin_addr.s_addr;
    uint8_t *dnsOct = (uint8_t*) &dnsSrv;
    printf("DNS: %u.%u.%u.%u\n", dnsOct[0], dnsOct[1], dnsOct[2], dnsOct[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Which gave me the following output:

> DNS: 127.0.0.53

How can I go about getting the actual nameserver IP on a system using systemd-resolved in C/C++?

Comment: The whole point of systemd-resolved is to be assimilated into the systemd Borg Collective. As far as you're concerned, human, systemd is your resolver of record. You will be assimilated. Resistance is futile. Of course, uninstalling systemd-resolved will ...resolve the issue. And is highly recommended.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Lol Indeed, I am not a fan of systemd-resolved. On my personal system, I delete the /etc/resolv.conf symlink and recreate it as a regular file with a static nameserver. However, the code I'm writing is going to be running on other systems that do have systemd-resolved installed.

Comment: Why isn't that what you want? If you had `nameserver 127.0.0.53` in `resolv.conf`, that's what you would expect to get from `res_init`. This is effectively the same.

Comment: @Barmar It's not what I want, because 127.0.0.53 is not the actual DNS server. It's effectively a proxy to the real DNS server. You are correct that the res_init function should return what is in resolv.conf. The problem is that resolv.conf has been hijacked by systemd.

Comment: See https://man.archlinux.org/man/resolved.conf.5 for the documentation of how `resolved` is configured.

Comment: @Barmar I appreciate the reference, but /etc/systemd/resolved.conf does not contain the IP of the actual DNS server being queried. I understand you feel that the IP 127.0.0.53 is adequate, however the customer that I am programming this for has clearly stated they want the IP address of the DNS server being queried, whether that is an IP on their local network or the IP of a public DNS server. They definitely do not want a loopback IP address.

Comment: Take a look at [source code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/resolve/resolvectl.c) of `resolvectl` command (verb_dns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`systemd-resolved` is a D-Bus service. You can reach it via D-Bus and there's a `DNS` property which contains the list of current DNS servers.

To test:

```
$ busctl get-property org.freedesktop.resolve1 /org/freedesktop/resolve1 org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager DNS
a(iiay) 2 0 2 4 1 1 1 1 0 2 4 8 8 8 8
```

The data format is described in the [org.freedesktop.resolve1 API spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.resolve1.html):

> Each structure in the array consists of a numeric network interface index, an address family, and a byte array containing the DNS server address (either 4 bytes in length for IPv4 or 16 bytes in lengths for IPv6).

So `a(iiay) 2 0 2 4 1 1 1 1 0 2 4 8 8 8 8` would mean 2 entries, AF_INET 1.1.1.1, AF_INET 8.8.8.8.

Here's a demo in C++ using systemd's built-in [sd-bus](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sd-bus.3.html) API:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
using namespace std::literals;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    sd_bus_error dbusErr{};
    sd_bus_message *msg{};
    sd_bus *dbus{};

    try {
        int err = sd_bus_open_system(&dbus);
        if (err < 0) {
            throw std::system_error(-err, std::system_category(), "can't connect to system D-Bus");
        }

        err = sd_bus_get_property(
                dbus,
                "org.freedesktop.resolve1",
                "/org/freedesktop/resolve1",
                "org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager",
                "DNS",
                &dbusErr,
                &msg,
                "a(iiay)");
        if (err < 0) {
            throw std::runtime_error("can't connect to systemd-resolved: "s + dbusErr.message);
        }

        err = sd_bus_message_enter_container(msg, SD_BUS_TYPE_ARRAY, "(iiay)");
        if (err < 0) {
            throw std::system_error(-err, std::system_category());
        }
        int32_t netif;
        int32_t af;
        size_t n;
        const void *addr;
        char buf[64];
        while (sd_bus_message_enter_container(msg, SD_BUS_TYPE_STRUCT, "iiay") > 0) {
            err = sd_bus_message_read(msg, "ii", &netif, &af);
            if (err < 0) {
                throw std::system_error(-err, std::system_category());
            }
            err = sd_bus_message_read_array(msg, 'y', &addr, &n);
            if (err < 0) {
                throw std::system_error(-err, std::system_category());
            }
            sd_bus_message_exit_container(msg);
            inet_ntop(af, addr, buf, sizeof(buf));
            std::cout << buf << "\n";
        }
        sd_bus_message_exit_container(msg);

    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    sd_bus_error_free(&dbusErr);
    sd_bus_message_unref(msg);
    sd_bus_unref(dbus);
}
```

You'll need to compile and link with `libsystemd` for the above to work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(ctest)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(SDBUS REQUIRED systemd)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE systemd)
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research, I have found another way to determine the actual DNS servers being queried by systemd-resolved. It turns out that systemd-resolved stores the IP addresses of the downstream DNS servers in the file `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`. On my system, the file looks like this:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 192.168.1.1
search .
```

It would be fairly straightforward to parse this file to grab the nameserver IP address:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char lineBuf[1024] = {0};
    std::ifstream sdResolv("/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf", std::ios::binary);
    
    uint8_t dnsIP[4] = {0};
    
    if(sdResolv.is_open() == true)
    {
        while(sdResolv.eof() == false)
        {
            sdResolv.getline(lineBuf, 1024);
            std::string line(lineBuf);
            
            size_t nsPos = line.find("nameserver ");
            
            if(nsPos == 0)
            {
                sscanf(lineBuf, "nameserver %hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", &dnsIP[0], &dnsIP[1], &dnsIP[2], &dnsIP[3]);
                break;
            }
        }
        
        sdResolv.close();
    }
    
    printf("DNS: %u.%u.%u.%u\n", dnsIP[0], dnsIP[1], dnsIP[2], dnsIP[3]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Note: While this is a valid solution, I have accepted the answer submitted by rustyx, as I feel that using DBUS is really the proper way to obtain the DNS server IP addresses in this case.